# Unable to Sort data using sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

my objective is to drag the products and customize its sorting order and prices.

I have successfully used drag and drop functionality but the sortable thing is not working.
Here is my fiddle

[Here is My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td0ncz29/)

**HTML**

```
   <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix productsUL ui-droppable" style="min-height: 120px;">
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l20$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="20" class="hfproductId" value="C4BAB31E-F95F-4DEC-A13E-CC66D8C02851">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="12" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">Black Coffee Tall</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l21$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="21" class="hfproductId" value="26E69E8E-9120-43CC-B8D0-2B4288BC6EAC">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="15" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">Black Coffee Grand</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l22$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="22" class="hfproductId" value="A2AF9FF7-E9CB-419A-B93C-CC3852E4908D">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="9" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">Coffee Latte</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l23$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="23" class="hfproductId" value="51DF12B7-D131-47C0-A2E5-273D963120A5">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="9" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">Coffee Latte Short</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l24$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="24" class="hfproductId" value="3DAED6FA-ECC5-4E4A-AA39-ADD303992807">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="12" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">Coffee Latte Tall</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l25$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="25" class="hfproductId" value="7205441D-7F59-4A46-BC54-F3A517B9A7EE">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="15" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">Coffee Latte Grand</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l26$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="26" class="hfproductId" value="C186AC2D-8F64-4875-9DC9-293F81CAAC40">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="9" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">vanilla Latte Coffee</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr productList ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: list-item;">
                                            <div class="divProduct" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/attach-blue.png);">
                                                <input name="l27$hfproductId" type="hidden" id="27" class="hfproductId" value="DC422052-9C65-4EB8-8ADE-9674B3AF9290">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control price txtNum" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event)" value="9" style="display: none;">
                                                <h5 class="ui-widget-header truncate">vanilla Latte  Short</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="click" style="text-align: center; width: 160px;">
                                                <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Select this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Select Product</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>


                            </ul>




                            <hr>
                               <h1>
                                    Final Grid
                                    </h1>
                              <div id="trash" class="row ui-widget-content ui-state-default sortable" style="min-height: 120px;">
                        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
            // There's the gallery and the trash
            var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
              $trash = $("#trash");

            // Let the gallery items be draggable
            $("li", $gallery).draggable({
                cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
                revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
                containment: "document",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move"
            });

            $trash.droppable({
                accept: "#gallery > li",
                classes: {
                    "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    debugger;
                    selectproduct(ui.draggable);
                }
            });
            // Let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
            $gallery.droppable({
                accept: "#trash li",
                classes: {
                    "ui-droppable-active": "custom-state-active"
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    deleteproduct(ui.draggable);
                }
            });

            // Image deletion function
            var recycle_icon = "<div style='text-align: center; width: 160px;'><a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this product' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Delete product</a></div>";
            function selectproduct($item) {
                $item.hide(function () {
                    var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ?
                      $("ul", $trash) :
                      $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset grid'/>").appendTo($trash);

                    $item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
                    $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).show(function () {
                        $item
                          .animate({})
                          .find("img")
                            .animate({ height: "36px" });
                    }).addClass('col-md-2 grid-item').find('.price').show();
                });
            }

            // Image recycle function
            var trash_icon = "<div style='text-align: center; width: 160px;'><a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Select this product' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Select product</a></div>";
            function deleteproduct($item) {
                $item.hide(function () {
                    $item
                      .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
                        .remove()
                      .end()
                      //.css("width", "96px")
                      .append(trash_icon)
                      .find("img")
                        .css("height", "72px")
                      .end()
                      .appendTo($gallery)
                      .show().removeClass('col-md-2 grid-item').find('.price').hide();
                });
            }

            // Image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
            function viewLargerImage($link) {
                var src = $link.attr("href"),
                  title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
                  $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");

                if ($modal.length) {
                    $modal.dialog("open");
                } else {
                    var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
                      .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        img.dialog({
                            title: title,
                            width: 400,
                            modal: true
                        });
                    }, 1);
                }
            }

            // Resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
            $("ul.gallery > li").off('click').on("click", function (event) {
                debugger;
                var $item = $(this),
                  $target = $(event.target);
                if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
                    selectproduct($item);
                    return false;
                } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
                    viewLargerImage($target);
                } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
                    deleteproduct($item);
                    return false;
                }
                else if ($target.is(".price")) {
                    $target.focus();
                }
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var new_id = 20;

$(".draggable").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: function () { 
        //alert($(this).attr('class'));

        var cloned = $(this).clone();
        cloned.attr('id', (++new_id).toString());
        
        return cloned;
    },
    distance: 20
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
    tolerance: 'pointer',

    accept: function (event, ui) {
        return true;
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        //alert($(this).parent().html());
        //alert($(ui.helper).attr('class'));
        var obj;
        if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('draggable')) {
            //alert('draggable');
          obj = $(ui.helper).clone();  
          obj.removeClass('draggable').addClass('editable').removeAttr('style');
          //obj.addClass('droppable');
          $(this).append(obj);

        }
        

        //alert($(this).parent().html());
    }
}).sortable({
    revert: false
});
```

```css
 .span3 {
     width:200px;
 }
    .droppable {
         height:400px;    
    }
 .droppable:hover {
//     background: red;
 }
 .draggable:hover {
     background: olive;
 }
 .editable:hover {
     background: cyan;
 }
 .ui-state-active {
     background: red;
 }
 .span3 {
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:1px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="draggable1" class= "draggable span3">
        <p>drag me</p>
    </div>
        <div id="draggable" class="draggable span3">
        <p>drag me</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- Editeur : grille pour déposer -->
<div id="editor-container">
    <div class="row droppable">
        <div class="editable span3">
            <p>Container</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- editor-container -->
```